# Insert a row as first row in the result of a dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot, dynamicquery

My below query is returning results successfully however I want to add a second header in the result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @SubHeader AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT
    @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(SP)
                   FROM #MyTable
                   WHERE SP != ''
                   GROUP BY SP
                   ORDER BY SP
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SET @query = 'SELECT ET,' + @cols + ' FROM 
                   (SELECT ET, SP, ET
                    FROM #MyTable 
                    WHERE SP != '''') x
               PIVOT
                   (MAX(ET)
                    FOR SP IN (' + @cols + ')) p '

PRINT @query
EXECUTE(@query);
```

The second header comes from the values in `@SubHeader` variable declared above.

Alternatively, if we can merge existing header and SubHeader and show like:

```
14-DEF, 15-GHI
```

Result presently is shown below:

[image]

I need output of headers as below:

[image]

**Edited**
The below schema can be considered from where the data is being pulled using above query:

```
declare @SampleData Table
(
    ET varchar(30),
    ProductId varchar(30),
    PID varchar(20),
    SP varchar(30),
    EventT Time,
    EventD Date
)
```

> ET - values in numeric: Any two digit numbers PID - abc, def, geh

> (This is the sub-header values of which this post is all about) SP -

> These are the numbers which are at present coming as Primary Header

> EventT - This is the first column in the result shown above

Rest other fields we don't need.

The records in this table look something like this:

[image]

Comment: This is a task for your presentation layer, not the SQL layer. Use something like SSRS and a Matrix, or if this is being presented in a company application, pivot the data in your application code before it's presented to the user.

Comment: @ThomA Can't use SSRS. I can do this in C# but was just thinking if we can get a concatenated header atleast.

Comment: SSRS was just an example, the key part of my comment is that it should be the presentation layer doing this work; you don't mention what that is in the question, so I can't comment further on that.

Comment: Your second image is not SQL. It shows a "table" with three columns in the first two rows and four columns in the third row. That is no-can-do.

Comment: @topsail Yes, it is an example of HTML coming from other Tool.

Comment: How is the SubHeader linked to the columns ? I mean how is 14 linked to Ext, or 16 linked to Lac ? Have you got it in another table ?

Comment: If you really want to solve this in the way you've proposed (despite the valid suggestions otherwise in the comments), then we'll need to see the DDL and some sample data for the `#MyTable` table to be able to answer.

Comment: @NandalalSeth - it would seem that the `@SubHeader` variable contains a comma delimited list of those SubHeadings, in the same way that `@cols` is populated with a comma delimited list of the column names. Although it begs the question, if the number of columns in `@cols` is dynamic, isn't the same true of the values in `@SubHeader`? We need to see source table DDL and example data for all inputs to be able to suggest a way to generate the desired output (with the caveat of this probably not being a good idea to do in SQL anyway).

Comment: @NandalalSeth Yes these are comma-delimited values. Let me send sample data.

Comment: This is probably gonna be quite ugly because you're also mixing different datatypes (ie. strings and some numbers). You can wrap your pivot in a subquery and add a union all select 'header1', 'header2' that is dynamically populated from `@SubHeader`, cast your pivot columns to nvarchar(max) and then you need to sort it correctly which usually means you need to wrap it once more.

Comment: @NandalalSeth Please check OP

Comment: @3N1GM4 Please check OP

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted column name in a format of "Header=Subheader", then below is my stab at it. I've changed the table definition a bit for ease of display while experimenting. Let me know if it helps.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #MyTable

Create table #MyTable
(
    ET varchar(30),
    PID varchar(20),
    SP varchar(30),
    EventT date
)

insert into #MyTable
VALUES
    (2042, 'Ext', 14, '2023-01-01' ),
    (null, 'Lac', 16, '2023-01-01' ),
    (11, 'Moi', 17, '2023-01-01' ),
    (11, 'Moi', 17, '2023-01-05' ),
    (35, 'Moi', 18, '2023-01-05' )

SELECT
    @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(PID+ '=' + SP)
    FROM #MyTable
    WHERE SP != ''
    GROUP BY PID+ '=' + SP
    ORDER BY PID+ '=' + SP
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')


SET @query = 'SELECT EventT,' + @cols + ' FROM 
                   (SELECT ET, PID + ''='' + SP AS SP, EventT
                    FROM #MyTable 
                    WHERE SP != '''') x
               PIVOT
                   (MAX(ET)
                    FOR SP IN (' + @cols + ')) p '

PRINT @query
EXECUTE(@query);
```

Comment: Let me try out this.